# React Native Radio Button Inside ListView

Tags: typescript, react-native, for-loop, radio-button

> DISCLAMER!! I've looked everywhere and tried: React-Native-Paper,
> react-native-radio-buttons-group and react-native-simple-radio-button
> but have not found what I'm looking for.  DISCLAMER!!

I'm trying to create radio buttons that should exist inside a loop. The loop, loops through a list of questions and underneath each question the user should be prompted with YES - NO - N/A. I've been able to accomplish this but everytime I click one radio button ALL the other radio buttons with the same answer gets checked.

[image]

See below for code!

This is the setup at the start of the component:

```
 const radioButtonsData: RadioButtonProps[] = [{
  id: '1', // acts as primary key, should be unique and non-empty string
  label: 'YES',
  value: 'na'
}, {
  id: '2',
  label: 'NO',
  value: 'no'
}, {
  id: '3',
  label: 'N/A',
  value: 'na'
}]

const [radioButtons, setRadioButtons] = useState<RadioButtonProps[]>(radioButtonsData)

function onPressRadioButton(radioButtonsArray: RadioButtonProps[]) {
        setRadioButtons(radioButtonsArray);
        console.log(radioButtonsArray)
    }
```

This is the actual loop:

```
 {props.subTaskList?.map((item, subTaskKeyAcc)  => {   
   return(
  <Collapsible collapsed={collapsed} align="center" key={subTaskKeyAcc}>
    
        <View>
        <Text>{item.subTaskName}</Text>
        <RadioGroup key={Math.random()}
            radioButtons={radioButtons} 
            onPress={onPressRadioButton} 
        />
</View>   
  </Collapsible>
        )})}
```

I'm guessing I've to create something unique for each radio button inside the loop, but I really can't find a solution for this problem. Would be very grateful for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else have this problem:

I solved it by installing react-native-flexi-radio-button. It was the only library that worked using a loop with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

OnPressRadio should be able to take a parameter which is your item id and change it in your subtasklist with that key using findIndex : identify your item with its key.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately, but it should be easier than that. Shouldn't I be able to just identify the rows somehow?